# VueJs +ElementUi Change method has no event data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

Fairly new to Vue & Element UI.
I'm trying to make a custom component using ElementUI autocomplete/select component.

My issue is that the @change method has no event.target.value value.

I get a

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of
> undefined"

error.
Below is my Vue component code.
I'm calling it as `<account-search v-model="newAccountForm.parent"></account-search>` from another component.

`v-on:change.native="handleChange"` doesn't seem to work at all.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <el-select :value="value" placeholder="Select" @change="handleChange">
            <el-option
                v-for="item in options"
                :key="item.value"
                :label="item.label"
                :value="item.value">
            </el-option>
        </el-select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "accountSearch",
        props: {
            value: {
                type: String
            }
        },
        data(){
            return {
                options:[
                    {
                        value: 1,
                        label: "hello"
                    },
                    {
                        value : 2,
                        label : "ola"
                    }
                ],
                loading: false,

            }
        },
        mounted() {

        },
        methods: {
            handleChange: function (event) {
                console.log(event.target.value);
                // this.$emit('input', value);
            },

        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing it to `@change.native="handleChange"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The param you get in `handleChange` is `value` not `event`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <el-select :value="value" placeholder="Select" @input="handleChange">
            <el-option
                v-for="item in options"
                :key="item.value"
                :label="item.label"
                :value="item.value">
            </el-option>
        </el-select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "accountSearch",
        props: {
            value: {
                type: String
            }
        },
        data(){
            return {
                options:[
                    {
                        value: 1,
                        label: "hello"
                    },
                    {
                        value : 2,
                        label : "ola"
                    }
                ],
                loading: false,

            }
        },
        mounted() {

        },
        methods: {
            handleChange: function (value) {
                console.log(value);
                this.$emit('input', value);
            },

        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```